# Angular2 - Changing classes dynamically

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have the following code repeatedly in my forms within my components:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label" for="description">Description</label>
  <input class="form-control form-control-lg" 
         id="description" 
         type="text" placeholder="..." 
         formControlName="description" 
         [ngClass]="{ 
           'form-control-warning': descriptionCtrl.untouched && descriptionCtrl.invalid, 
           'form-control-success': descriptionCtrl.valid, 
           'form-control-danger': descriptionCtrl.touched && descriptionCtrl.invalid }">
</div>
... Another "blocks" with the same code
```

So, in order to simplify this, I've created the following *method*:

```
handleClass = (control: AbstractControl): any => {
  if (control.valid) {
    return 'form-control-success';
  } else {
    if (control.touched) {
      return 'form-control-danger';
    } else {
      return 'form-control-warning';
    }
  }
}
```

In template:

```
[ngClass]="handleClass(control)"
```

However this is still not what I want, since I need to do create this method on **all** components. I'm looking for a general way to do this dynamically.

PS: All inputs in my project have the same rule as the input above.

What's the best way to accomplish this? I hope my question was clear enough.

Comment: learn about directives, it is a powerful way to manipulate dom element.So you will basically get the dom elements and do whatever you want to do.
(https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a directive to handle this, like so:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[formValidBorders]'})
export class FormValidBorders implements OnChanges {
    @Input('formValidBorders') formValue: AbstractControl;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    ngOnChanges(){
        this.el.nativeElement.className = this.handleClass(formValue);
    }

    private handleClass(control: AbstractControl) {

      if (control.valid) {
        return 'form-control-success';
      } 
      else if (control.touched) {
          return 'form-control-danger';
        } 
      else {
          return 'form-control-warning';

      }
    }
}
```

Then on your element:

```
<input class="form-control form-control-lg" 
         id="description" 
         type="text" placeholder="..." 
         formControlName="description" 
         [formValidBorders]="form.get('description')">
```

Something like this should work, with imports of course.

Comment: Remove the return type annotation please, `any` is absolutely wrong here. Also, this doesn't make any sense since you are not doing anything with the result.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I accidently saved the wrong copy of the answer, the updated answer is in place.

Comment: You are using a return type of `any`, what are you returning? (hint the compiler knows best if you let it do its job)

Comment: Oh!  Sorry, I copied that from his question.  That doesn't need a return type.

Comment: Right, it is often best to let it infer the type in the other case too. It is always better than using `any`. So in either case you can leave off the return type which, incidentally, is `void` in your updated answer.

Comment: Right, I agree.  The goal of the question was really how to encapsulate that logic (the directive) so I wasn't really paying attention to the business logic area.

Comment: indeed, and there generally no need to think about the types so long as you do not prevent type inference. Regardless, I liked where the original answer was going better. Returning the value was much cleaner, you just had the wrong type annotation.

Comment: I'll update the question to reflect your preference, but again I was really just trying to demonstrate the concept of the custom directive instead of a typescript lesson.

Comment: Do whatever you like, I was just making a suggestion. I removed downvote a while back when you fixed the type.